# Folder "Desktop" can't be found

Tags: macos, error

This is the error message I am receiving as I try to attach something from my desktop to an email.

> “Desktop” can’t be opened because the original item can’t be found.

What should I do?

Comment: You should provide more information: what email program do you use, how do you attach something from your desktop, step by step. Screenshot of the error would also help.

Comment: You also want to update your title to something a bit more meaningful other than the OS we *assume* you are using.